# Failing to conda build R package

Tags: r, dependencies, conda, conda-build

I'm trying to use conda and Jupypter to write some R code. I found a useful package called 'treatSens' and tried to install via conda following the instructions [here](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/4355).

```
conda install conda-build
conda skeleton cran treatSens
conda build r-treatsens
conda install -c local r-treatsens
```

Then I got this error `conda_build.exceptions.DependencyNeedsBuildingError: Unsatisfiable dependencies for platform osx-64: {"r-dbarts[version='>=0.9_1']"}`. How do I satisfy this dependency? Any suggestion is appreciated.

===UPDATE====

Added `--recursive` then I got a new error, posted a new question
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53637414/conda-build-r-package-fails-at-c-compiler-issue-on-macos-mojave).

Comment: Is this error showing after executing the last command? Are there any errors/warnings before?

Comment: @godot Yeah that was after the last command. Updated the question, now it's something about C compiler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
conda install conda-build
conda skeleton cran --recursive treatSens
conda build r-treatsens
conda install -c local r-treatsens
```

The recursive option should account for the dependencies you need.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Added recursive and got this error about C compiler in the process of installing the dependency `dbarts`. I found this https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/9872 but not sure what to do yet

Comment: Are you using MacOS Mojave? There are some notes here about it getting in the way of 32bit builds: https://github.com/ValveSoftware/Proton/issues/108

Comment: Yes Mojave, I think that's the right direction. Now I need to figure out how to customize conda build to use the right C compiler. I found https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/build-packages/compiler-tools.html but can't figure out how to set it