# Conda build R package fails at C compiler issue on MacOS Mojave

Tags: r, gcc, anaconda, conda, conda-build

I'm trying to install an R package called treatSens with conda to use it in Jupyter notebook. The commands I executed:

`conda install conda-build
conda skeleton cran treatSens
conda build r-treatsens
conda install -c local r-treatsens`

And I got the error about C compiler

```
* installing *source* package ‘dbarts’ ...
** package ‘dbarts’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
checking for gcc... x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/Users/myusername/anaconda3/conda-bld/r-dbarts_1543961434509/myenvname':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘dbarts’
```

My clang version:

```
clang version 4.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_401/final)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin18.2.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Users/myusername/anaconda3/envs/myenvname/bin
```

Looking into the config.log file I see

```
configure:3570: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang -V >&5
clang-4.0: error: argument to '-V' is missing (expected 1 value)
clang-4.0: error: no input files
configure:3581: $? = 1
configure:3570: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang -qversion >&5
clang-4.0: error: unknown argument: '-qversion'
clang-4.0: error: no input files
configure:3581: $? = 1
configure:3601: checking whether the C compiler works
configure:3623: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang -march=core2 -mtune=haswell -mssse3 -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -O2 -pipe -I/Users/myusername/anaconda3/envs/work/conda-bld/r-dbarts_1543961045662/_h_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehol/include -fdebug-prefix-map=/Users/myusername/anaconda3/envs/work/conda-bld/r-dbarts_1543961045662/work=/usr/local/src/conda/r-dbarts-0.9_5 -fdebug-prefix-map=/Users/myusername/anaconda3/envs/work/conda-bld/r-dbarts_1543961045662/_h_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehol=/usr/local/src/conda-prefix -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -mmacosx-version-min=10.9 -I/Users/myusername/anaconda3/envs/work/conda-bld/r-dbarts_1543961045662/_h_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehol/include -Wl,-pie -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -Wl,-dead_strip_dylibs -Wl,-rpath,/Users/myusername/anaconda3/envs/work/conda-bld/r-dbarts_1543961045662/_h_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehol/lib -L/Users/myusername/anaconda3/envs/work/conda-bld/r-dbarts_1543961045662/_h_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehol/lib conftest.c  >&5
ld: warning: ignoring file /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/lib/libSystem.tbd, file was built for unsupported file format ( 0x2D 0x2D 0x2D 0x20 0x21 0x74 0x61 0x70 0x69 0x2D 0x74 0x62 0x64 0x2D 0x76 0x33 ) which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64): /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/lib/libSystem.tbd
ld: dynamic main executables must link with libSystem.dylib for architecture x86_64
clang-4.0: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

It seems it's a problem about Conda build using the certain version of Apple C compiler. My guess is that I need to customize the C compiler for conda build. So my question becomes

1. What correct gcc version do I need.
2. How to set it for conda build.

Comment: I do not have Mojave installed so I cannot try this but in the past I have had issues like these after updating macOS and I had to open up Xcode and click some 'confirm' and 'agree' buttons before I could get everything working again. Might be worth a shot

Comment: It appears your clang is not in a typical location for one thing. Have yopu reviewed the Developer page for Macos R?  And have you reviewed this answer to a similar question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52509602/cant-compile-c-program-on-a-mac-after-upgrade-to-mojave

Comment: @42- The above is in my conda environment. I tried to install xcode cmd line tools 9.3 and removed the newest version, but I don't know how to make it the compiler for conda install.

Comment: To further clarify, I can install this package in RStudio with no problem. My problem is with conda.

Comment: I doubt that conda  uses the same environment variables as Rstudio. That’s a common source of confusion for new Rstudio users when they cannot figure out why things work in Terminal-launched R but not in Rstudio.

Answer (score 4):

As a quick and dirty workaround (from this [comment](https://github.com/conda-forge/compilers-feedstock/issues/6#issuecomment-463256863)), I was able to install packages in R using below code in RStudio (opened in conda env)

```
Sys.setenv(CONDA_BUILD_SYSROOT="/")
```

Now, you can install any R package via RStudio Console e.g.

```
install.packages("tidyverse")
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

There are several things you must do to get things building properly in MacOS Mojave.  For reasons mysterious to me, the Anaconda folks are [not keen](https://github.com/conda-forge/compilers-feedstock/issues/6) to make this smooth, which is especially maddening for those of us who use esoteric R packages.  I will write what seems current as of 2019-04-20:

**1. Install Xcode (v10.2.1)**

**2. Install headers** in the place open source tends to expect finding them.  From the command line:

```
open /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Packages/macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14.pkg
```

**3. Install the command-line tools**

- As a belt-and braces approach, I downloaded  and installed the DMG `Command_Line_Tools_macOS_10.14_for_Xcode_10.2.1` from https://developer.apple.com/download/more/
- I believe this is also what is done by `xcode-select --install`.  If you run that command (once the tools are installed), you should see the message

> ```
> xcode-select: error: command line tools are already installed, use "Software Update" to install updates
> ```

**4. Download a copy of older MacOS SDK files**.  For example, from [here](https://github.com/phracker/MacOSX-SDKs)

**5. Create a directory `/opt`**

```
sudo mkdir /opt
```

**6. Copy the SDK files there**

```
sudo cp -r ~/Downloads/MacOSX10.9.sdk /opt/

sudo chmod -R a+rX /opt
```

**7. Create a `conda_build_config.yaml` file** that will be referenced by Conda-build and related software.  It should contain the following

> ```
> macos_min_version:
>   - 10.9
> macos_machine:
>   - x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0
> MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET:
>   - 10.9
> CONDA_BUILD_SYSROOT:            # [osx]
>   - /opt/MacOSX10.9.sdk          # [osx]
> ```

In a terminal you can do that with:

```
mkdir ~/.conda || echo 'Dir already present'
echo "macos_min_version:" >> ~/.conda/conda_build_config.yaml
echo "  - 10.9" >> ~/.conda/conda_build_config.yaml
echo "macos_machine:" >> ~/.conda/conda_build_config.yaml
echo "  - x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0" >> ~/.conda/conda_build_config.yaml
echo "MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET:" >> ~/.conda/conda_build_config.yaml
echo "  - 10.9" >> ~/.conda/conda_build_config.yaml
echo "CONDA_BUILD_SYSROOT:" >> ~/.conda/conda_build_config.yaml
echo "  - /opt/MacOSX10.9.sdk" >> ~/.conda/conda_build_config.yaml
```

**8. Tell Conda about your YAML file** via your `.condarc`.  It should contain the lines:

> ```
> conda_build:   
>   config_file: ~/.conda/conda_build_config.yaml
> ```

which can be accomplished using

```
echo "conda_build:" >> ~/.condarc
echo "  config_file: ~/.conda/conda_build_config.yaml" >> ~/.condarc
```